# AutoFixture with AutoMoq always returns the same instance after Customization

Tags: c#, moq, autofixture, automoq

I have the following code to set up some response from a mock client (some parts of the code are omitted for brevity):

```
IFixture fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization() 
                   { ConfigureMembers = true, GenerateDelegates = true });

CustomNetworkCall<ResponseObject> GetNewResponse()
{
  var response = fixture.Create<ResponseObject>();
  fixture.Customize<ResponseObject>(ro => ro.FromFactory(() =>
  {
    response.DataList.AddRange(fixture.CreateMany<DataObject>(random.Next(3, 10)));
    return response;
  })
  .With(item => item.Id, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())  
  );
  return fixture.Create<CustomNetworkCall<ResponseObject>>();
}

//setup for mock code
clientMock.Setup(client => 
   client.GetResponseAsync(
       It.IsAny<IdDescription>(),
       It.IsAny<DataValidation>(), 
       It.IsAny<DateTime?>(), 
       It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
  .Returns(GetNewResponse());
```

I use the mocked out method to get a new instance but I always get the firstly created `ResponseObject` instance with the same `Id`:

```
try
{
    //I always get the same instance!!!
    responseObject = await basicClient.GetResponseAsync(new(){Id = Guid.NewGuid()}); 
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Logger.LogError(e, e.Message);
}
```

Unfortunately the [documentation](https://autofixture.github.io/docs/fixture-customization-customize-and-build-dsl/) is "quite" empty on this topic.

What should I change to get a *new instance* every time I call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//...
.Returns(GetNewResponse());
```

will return the same instance provided when `GetNewResponse()` is invoked.

If you want a different instance per call then refactor the `.Returns` to invoke a delegate

```
//...
.Returns(() => GetNewResponse()); //<-- note the function in .Returns
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the necessary step.